# $broadcast and $on listener not working after state change with different paramters

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope, angular-ui-router

I have a ui-router state with params:

```
.config(function config( $stateProvider ) {
  $stateProvider.state( 'editor', {
    url: '/{userName}/{presentationTitle}/editor',
    views: {
      "main": {
        controller: 'EditorCtrl',
        templateUrl: 'editor/editor.tpl.html'
      }
    },
    data:{ pageTitle: 'Editor' }
  });
})
```

The state controller *EditorCtrl* uses $broadcast at some point, to indicate the directives involved, that all data has been loaded.

```
$scope.$broadcast("allDataLoaded");
```

and of course there are listeners in directives:

```
scope.$on("allDataLoaded", function () { do something })
```

Everything works fine the first time. Then the same state gets called again from within a directive with a different parameter: presentationTitle is changed.

```
$state.go('editor', {presentationTitle:newValue});
```

And this time the broadcast are not working to my big surprise. The EditorCtrl code executes, it reaches the line of the $broadcast and then the listeners are suddenly not responding anymore.

What am I missing here?

Answer (score 4):

I found the problem myself. During the first time a few async things went on BEFORE the $broadcast happened and all went fine. But the second time - after the state change - these were not happening again and therefore the $broadcast came simply to early for the directives.

Wrapping the $broadcast in a $timoutout solved everything:

```
$timeout(function(){
    $scope.$broadcast("allDataLoaded");
});
```

Comment: thanks. This solve my problem when I set a `20` millisecond for timeout.

Comment: What is it with Angularjs and $timeouts? I feel like to any given problem the solution is always $timeout. Thanks for pointing it out (again) even though it shoul be obvious ;-)